# How to separately define and pass a collection name to a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following cloud function which creates a doc in a 'student_history' collection for every new doc creation in 'students' collection:

```
document("students/{student_id}").onCreate(
  async (snap, context) =>   {
    const values = snap.data();
    console.log(values);
    console.log(typeof values);
    return db.collection("student_history").add({...values, createdAt:FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
  });
```

I wanted to generalise this for 2 other collections. Something like this:

```
export const onStudentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/students/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
export const onBatchCreated = functions.firestore.document('/batches/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
export const onTeacherCreated = functions.firestore.document('/teachers/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
```

My question is, how can I have my onDocCreated function receive a collection name (eg, students, batches or teachers) and make an entry to a corresponding students_history, batches_history or teachers_history?

```
async function onDocCreated() {
  async (snap, context) => {
    const values = snap.data();
    console.log(values);
    console.log(typeof values);
    return db.collection("NAMEOFTHECOLLECTION_history").add({
      ...values,
      createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to pass take the `snap` and `context` params in `onDocCreated()` function itself. The `snap` is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) so you can use get collection ID from the `parent` property as shown below:

```
async function onDocCreated(snap, context) {
    const values = snap.data();
    console.log(values);
   
    const collectionName = snap.ref.parent.id; 
    console.log("Collection Name:", collectionName)
   
    return db.collection(`${collectionName}_history`).add({
        ...values,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried implementing your solution and got the following error:

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/eshaangupta/Desktop/prototype/functions/index.js:38
    export const onStudentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/students/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Unable to post the entire traceback error here, let me know if I should post it on discord.

Comment: @EshaanGupta can create a [Gist](https://gist.github.com) and share the complete functions index.js file as a whole instead of small code snippets? Also do you have ESLint? It could be that cause the code seems to work.

Comment: Okay sure: https://gist.github.com/e-shaan/c3ff5ecef9b050a91291e96b7ef21a70, yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Dharamaj 's answer,

As per his suggestion

```
export const onStudentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/students/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
export const onBatchCreated = functions.firestore.document('/batches/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
export const onTeacherCreated = functions.firestore.document('/teachers/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
exports.onStudentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/students/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
exports.onBatchCreated = functions.firestore.document('/batches/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
exports.onTeacherCreated = functions.firestore.document('/teachers/{id}').onCreate(onDocCreated);
```